# Importing sql dumped file from workbench into Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am trying to import a dump sql file generated from Mysql Workbench. I have two schemas, many tables and procedures. Furthermore, I have some users in that database which creates some temporary tables.
I have seen a document which says to remove keyword as DEFINER and I have done that but the problem is still happening when I import my dump.sql in CloudSQL.

The problem faced is **"ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 24: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation Import error: exit status 1".**

What I notice is that Importing can not run CREATE, DROP.
Does anyone could help me to get my dump file imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to import to Cloud SQL MySQL you need to follow certain requirements as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing#before_you_begin). One of them is that the dump must not contain **stored procedures**. You stated you do have, so you'd have to exclude them from the dump file and recreate them after importing the data.